# EF Core 6 and Signal R to update a web UI grid based on table being updated/Inserted

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

Hey all soooo heres the scoop. i have a real time logging instance inserting rows into a table (log) and im attempting to use signal R to update the UI with out having to refresh the page. i got it working using SQL dependency objects but i wat to use linq and the DB context to "listen" for changes to the table and update the UI grid automajacly

i have tried to use the built in change tracking to EF and i can get the rows to load but one that happens there are not further updates to the grid.... again using the "old" way with a SQL dependency works but im having a hell of a time

Comment: If you want to add listen for database change, I need say no.  But if you want to listen ef core run update operation, you could use the code: `var entries = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);` after update linq before savechanges code to listen. Then invoke the SignalR when  the value of  `entries. Any()` is true to achieve your requirement.